# Move DB cursor id after manual insert

Tags: django, psql, django-database

I'm facing a case where I have to manually insert data from old DB into a new one. The new one is a DB that'll be used by a Django application.

For that I have CSV file or whatever that I iterate over, and the thing is that I also use the id from this file, because I need to keep it.

For instance I do :

```py
from django.db import connections

cursor = connections["default"].cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table (id, name) VALUES (3, 'test')")
```

If I use such ID (3), the next time I'll want to insert data through my django application, it'll create a record with ID 1, then ID 2, then I'll have an error because it'll try to create data for ID 3.

How can I make it skip existing ID ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You cannot, but you can solve the problem by using `SELECT setval('sequence_name', 1234567);` to adjust the underlying sequence.

Comment: `setval` works, but you maybe should rethink your model. Add a field called `old_id = models.IntegerField`, and just let the db create new IDs.

Comment: I don't want to add extra field for that though. My application will be deployed several times (single tenant) and I need to do this only for people that want to migrate data from their old tool. I don't want to have extra field "just in case".

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can `setval` be used on a particular table ? It seems like it's applied globally.

Comment: It is applied to a particular sequence. You'd have to find out the name of the sequence that is used to generate the values.